# Why does using an ObjectInputStream in conjunction with GZIP cause the O.I.S. block the thread?

Tags: java, gzip, objectinputstream

I currently have a simple system set up where an ObjectInputStream reads directly from a GZIPInputStream which is attached to a client Socket's input stream:

```
        InputStream stream = s.getInputStream();

        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(stream);

        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(gis);
        System.out.println(input);

        return input;
```

The problem with this is, the ObjectInputStream attempts to read the stream header and begins blocking the thread. Why is this happening, and/or how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Do you think this helps? http://home.comcast.net/~cgokey/java/zlib/index.html . Only trying to help out. Havent played with it though.

Comment: Looks great so far, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

InputStream read() will block until data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.  To prevent the main code path from blocking, use a background thread to do the read. Of course, the background thread will block until bytes are available.  Unexpected blocking can be the fault of the sending side.

Comment: It's the ObjectInputStream that's blocking, and that's because the header isn't being decompressed by the GZIPInputStream. :/